# My javaFx program runs in intellij but I cannot compile and run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have created a JavaFX program in Intellij idea. The program has only two classes named Main.java and Cart.java. When I run Main in Intellij, it works fine and opens the program but when I open it in terminal I get an error at compiling. I first tried javac TopCart.java which gave errors it was not finding my cart class.

I first tried javac TopCart.java which gave errors it was not finding my cart class. Then I tried javac Main.java Cart.java ( I have never had to specify additional class files in intelliJ before) and it compiled but when I attempted to run it I get `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

the start of my code is this:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;


public class Main extends Application {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

I am not sure if it has to do with how I have my override statement but it looks like this

```
 @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        stage = primaryStage;
```

I am trying to make it run out of command prompt as well as eventually build a jar file that will run it. I would be very grateful of how to fix this and why it is not working. The sample package is the default set by intellij

Comment: Can you add the steps when you are trying to run? Also can we see a snippet of the cart class.

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?

Comment: I am using the JavaFX that came with the JDK version 1.8.0_91 and my code for the cart class is 
```
package sample;

public class Cart {
    int cartNmbr;
    int bldgNmbr;
    boolean status;
    boolean gas;
    boolean key;

    public Cart(int inputCartNmbr,int inputBldgNmbr, boolean inputStatus, boolean inputGas, boolean inputKey) {
        this.cartNmbr = inputCartNmbr;
        this.bldgNmbr = inputBldgNmbr;
        this.status = inputStatus;
        this.gas = inputGas;
        this.key = inputKey;

    }
}
```

Comment: when I run it I first compile with javac Main.java Cart.java which does not return errors. Then I run with java Main like I have done with none javafx files..this is my first javafx project so is there something additional needed other than the imports?

Comment: I found another question similar and was able to run it in command line by changing how I was running it. I was using java Main and needed java sample.Main

Answer (score 0):

I found another question similar and was able to run it in command line by changing how I was running it. I was using java Main and needed java sample.Main